# geopandas spatial join extremely slow

Tags: python, spatial-join, geopandas, rtree

I am using the code below to find a country (and sometimes state) for millions of GPS points. The code currently takes about one second per point, which is incredibly slow. The shapefile is 6 MB.

I read that geopandas uses rtrees for spatial joins, making them incredibly efficient, but this does not seem to work here. What am I doing wrong? I was hoping for a thousand points per second or so.

The shapefile and csv can be downloaded here (5MB): https://www.dropbox.com/s/gdkxtpqupj0sidm/SpatialJoin.zip?dl=0

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame, read_file
from geopandas.tools import sjoin
from shapely.geometry import Point, mapping,shape
import time


#parameters
shapefile="K:/.../Shapefiles/Used/World.shp"
df=pd.read_csv("K:/.../output2.csv",index_col=None,nrows=20)# Limit to 20 rows for testing    

if __name__=="__main__":
    start=time.time()
    df['geometry'] = df.apply(lambda z: Point(z.Longitude, z.Latitude), axis=1)
    PointsGeodataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)
    PolygonsGeodataframe = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(shapefile)
    PointsGeodataframe.crs = PolygonsGeodataframe.crs
    print time.time()-start
    merged=sjoin(PointsGeodataframe, PolygonsGeodataframe, how='left')
    print time.time()-start
    merged.to_csv("K:/01. Personal/04. Models/10. Location/output.csv",index=None)
    print time.time()-start
```

Comment: Your data link is 404

Answer (score 21, accepted):

adding the argument predicate='within' in the sjoin function speeds up the point-in-polygon operation dramatically.

Default value is predicate='intersects', which I guess would also lead to correct result, but is 100 to 1000 times slower.

Comment: To anyone reading this, this does not mean that `within` is *generally* somehow faster, read nick_g's answer below.

Answer (score 17):

What's likely going on here is that only the dataframe on the right is fed into the rtree index:
https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/tools/sjoin.py#L48-L55
Which for an `predicate="intersects"` run would mean the Polygon was fed into the index, so for every point, the corresponding polygon is found through the rtree index.

But for `predicate="within"`, the geodataframes are flipped since the operation is actually the inverse of `contains`:
https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/master/geopandas/tools/sjoin.py#L41-L43

So what happened when you switched the `predicate` from `predicate="intersects"` to `predicate="within"` is that for every polygon, the corresponding points are found through the rtree index, which in your case sped up the query.

Comment: You used non-permanent URLs, could you update them to a specific revision maybe?

Comment: link to most recent release with the issue persisting:
https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/v0.12.2/geopandas/tools/sjoin.py#L216

Answer (score 13):

The question asks how to take advantage of r-tree in geopandas spatial joins, and another responder correctly points out that you should use 'within' instead of 'intersects'. However, you can also take advantage of an r-tree spatial index in geopandas while using `intersects`/`intersection`, as demonstrated in this **[geopandas r-tree tutorial](http://geoffboeing.com/2016/10/r-tree-spatial-index-python/)**:

```
spatial_index = gdf.sindex
possible_matches_index = list(spatial_index.intersection(polygon.bounds))
possible_matches = gdf.iloc[possible_matches_index]
precise_matches = possible_matches[possible_matches.intersects(polygon)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to the issue in geopandas discussed [in this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/215725/14280) and seen [here](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/blob/v0.12.2/geopandas/tools/sjoin.py#L216) in the latest release:

If you have two geodataframes and want to perform an `intersects` operation and you know which spatial index should be queried, you can join from small to large and use `how="right"` to force this index to be used:

```
small_gdf.sjoin(large_gdf, predicate="intersects", how="right")
```