# Write a Spatial Join output to a CSV?

Tags: geopandas, python-3

I am trying [this](https://github.com/datadesk/geopandas-spatial-join-example/blob/master/notebook.ipynb) example with different input files. My aim is to merge the country and point tables into one table using ***sjoin*** from geopandas and write to a CSV file. I took a look at [1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175228/geopandas-spatial-join-extremely-slow?rq=1).
When I run the second line of code below, It takes really long time.

1. My Input point file is about 62kb and my country file is about 8kb is that the reason for the time consumption ?
2. Is there any other efficient way to write to a CSV? Or is there any mistake in my code below ?

```
merged_gdf = gpd.sjoin(point_gdf, country_gdf, how="right", op="within")
merged_gdf.to_csv("plswork.csv",index=False,mode='w')
```

Comment: OMG ,Thank you, it was indeed the geometry that delayed the processing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are including the geometries as text in the csv which can slow down the export since each vertice is written as text. If you dont need them use [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
merged_gdf.drop('geometry',axis=1).to_csv(r'plswork.csv')
```